# How to implement singleton without using static method?

Tags: design-patterns

Generally, the singleton pattern is implemented by creating a class with a static method that creates a new instance of the class if one does not exist. If an instance already exists, it simply returns a reference to that object. To make sure that the object cannot be instantiated any other way, the constructor is made private. Is there any other way for creating a singleton ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Actually, I wanted to know, is there any ways to implement singleton without using static method as well as variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A static public read-only variable

(if supported by your language)

## C#:

```
public static readonly MyClass singleton = new MyClass(); // create at class/assembly load/access
```

## Java:

```
public static final MyClass singleton;

static {
    singleton = new MyClass();
}
```

## C++:

```
// header
class MyClass {
public:
   static MyClass singleton; // value, created before main, or at dll load
   static MyClass const * singleton; // const ptr to non-const value, created before main 
private:
   MyClass();
   ~MyClass();
   MyClass(const Myclass&) = delete; // c++11, remove default implementation  
}

// in cpp:
MyClass Myclass::singleton;
MyClass const* MyClass::singleton = new MyClsas;
```

With most compilers/languages, this avoids the create-on-demand problem which requires thread-locking and order-of-initialization/destruction problems.

### Explicit via main() or dependency-injection

However, my preferred way of doing singletons is to create a field/property somewhere and initialize that explicitly (in main or via some dependency-injection framework. This helps quite a bit with managing many singleton-types, especially with testing.

You could additionally test and prevent set the singleton property from being set more than once if you wanted to, at least when not running tests.

```
 int main()
 {
      // Just set it. Use discipline to prevent others
      MyClass.singleton = new MyClass();

      // Use function, then we can enforce set-only-once, if required
      MyClass.setSingleton(new MyClass());          

      // dependency injection via env-vars! :)
      MyClass::setSingleton(ClassFactory::create(getenv("MYCLASS_SINGLETON_TYPE"));

      mainLoop();
 }
```

### Store the singleton somewhere else

It can often be convenient to have a "manager" or "registry" or whatever to hold all the global objects. Then that class could be responsible for creating/setting up all your big singleton-ish objects that you need.

That way, the class that you use as a singleton doesn't need to care about being a singleton. Very useful when testing or "reset" style scenarios.

It also helps by centralizing all these "big" objects somewhere so that the global state can be found and managed in a single place, rather than between 5-25 different classes all over your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can synchronize within the method the most common pattern called double checked locking.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking

Here there are some code samples about double checked locking.:

http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.il/2014/05/double-checked-locking-on-singleton-in-java.html

**EDIT**

The key benefit of using double checked is that you can use run the function with more then one thread while only the *critical* part of creating the new object is done under lock.